# rhive.write.table() : argument "tableName" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, hive

I imported csv data and tried to save in Hive using the following code but in vain:

```
   > base2<-read.csv("/home/hadoop/R/base.csv")
   > base2
       id devid   name
    1   7  1007      R
    2   8  1008 python
    3   9  1009   Ruby


   > rhive.write.table()
   >Error: argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

I also checked the type is data.frame, so I do not know what the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass any argument to the function `rhive.write.table()`.

Try `rhive.write.table(base2)`.

Comment: Thanks, but after using rhive.write.table(base2). It still shows the error messsage: Error: argument "tableName" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0):

I used the following codes and created the table in Hive sucessfully, but also come out the masseage as well;

```
    > rhive.write.table(base2, tableName = 'base2', sep=',') 

    Error: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000,     
    cause: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid 
    path ''/rhive/data/root/base2_64dbfcaf0e6fbd092165717b91de64'': No 
    files matching path 
    hdfs://master:9000/rhive/data/root/base2_64dbfcaf0e6fbd092165717b91de64
```

we can found base2 table created in the table list already, but no rows inserted at all:

```
    > rhive.list.tables()
           tab_name
  1        base
  2        base2
  3        emplyoee

    >rhive.query("SELECT * FROM base2")
  [1] base2.id    base2.devid base2.name
  <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```